# Re-run iATS recurring contributions that failed due to bad iATS account credentials?

Tags: contributions, recurring-contributions, iats

iATS credentials were messed up for a couple of days in December, and now I have lots of recurring contributions that failed, with source="iATS Payments Recurring Contribution (id=N) Agent code has not been set up on the authorization system. Please call iATS at 1-888-955-5455."

Is there a way to re-run those recurring contributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the date for the next scheduled recurrence.
Table civicrm_contribution_recur > Column next_sched_contribution_date

Change it to today and run your cron job or change it to tomorrow and it should process them with tomorrows transactions.

Comment: That’s correct; if you have lots - use mysql to set all next scheduled dates of e.g. series with status in progress and next scheduled date in the past to tomorrow; if you need a user GUI -> use Views Bulk Operations with CiviCRM Entity

Comment: Worthwhile note: be sure to note the next_sched_contribution_date value before changing it, and adjust afterward, if necessary, to an appropriate day-of-month.

Comment: Check out this: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/wiki/Recurring-Contribution-Failure-Handling
Short answer: if it was only a few days, then it might have been handled automatically. You can configure some aspects of how the extension handles failed recurring contributions, and getting email alerts about them might be a good idea in your case.